# How to serve collected static files with Django's development server?

Tags: django

I am trying to make Django's development server to serve static files that have been collected by the `python manage.py collectstatic` command. For now I failed.

My Django settings file declares this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(WWW_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'front', 'public'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'front', 'dist')
)
```

This makes the `collectstatic` command copying files from `os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'front', 'public')` and `os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'front', 'dist')` to `STATIC_ROOT`, and it works perfectly.

I was assuming that it would also tell Django to look for static files into the `STATIC_ROOT` directory, I was wrong. Even if the `STATIC_ROOT` directory does not exists, Django is able to serve the static files. But if the `os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'front')` is missing, Django no more serve the static files.

This shows that Django continues to serve static files from the sources directories and not from `STATIC_ROOT`.

So I would like to know if there is a way to instruct Django's development server to serve static files from `STATIC_ROOT`. Any hint?

**EDIT:**

After @e4c5 's answer I modified my root `urls.py` like this:

```
static_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(static_patterns)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/resa/', include('reservation.urls')),
    url(r'^api/auth/', include('authentication.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

unfortunately, it does not have the expected result and Django does not find static files in `STATIC_ROOT`, I doubt that it actually looks for static files in `STATIC_ROOT`.

here is what I can see in the console when accessing to the index page:

```
[04/Jun/2017 16:18:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1411
[04/Jun/2017 16:18:05] "GET /static/style/index.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1759
[04/Jun/2017 16:18:05] "GET /static/style/react-datetime.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1786
[04/Jun/2017 16:18:05] "GET /static/style/react-big-calendar.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798
[04/Jun/2017 16:18:05] "GET /static/script/bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1762
```

here are the content of the settings variables:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.WWW_PATH
'/home/tryph/PycharmProjects/resa/www'
>>> settings.STATIC_ROOT
'/home/tryph/PycharmProjects/resa/www/static'
>>> settings.STATIC_URL
'/static/'
```

here is the content of the `WWW_PATH` directory:

```
/home/tryph/PycharmProjects/resa/www
└── static
    ├── admin
    │   [...]
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── index.html
    ├── rest_framework
    │   [...]
    ├── script
    │   └── bundle.js
    └── style
        ├── index.css
        ├── react-big-calendar.css
        └── react-datetime.css
```

Comment: Isn't your manage.py in a folder named back and `ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)`
`WWW_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'www')`

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(WWW_PATH, 'static')` means it is looking for the static files in `app/back/www/static`?

Comment: @filtfilt Thanks for the suggestion. The paths defined in the `settings.py` seem to be defined relatively from the `settings.py` location, not the `manage.py` one. So everything looks good for the `STATIC_ROOT` path. Please see my edit for more detail.

Comment: What about this? *all static files are managed by gulp, and live in 'public' and 'dist' dirs*

Comment: @Robert I did not remember this comment, it is probably an artifact from an old copy/paste. I will remove it to avoid confusion. Actually, the `public` and `dist` dirs are where the front project stores the styles, scripts, icons, etc... and they are the dirs where the `manage.py collectstatic` command looks for static files to copy in `www/static`

Comment: Has the server been reloaded ?

Comment: @e4c5 yep. I just tried to start it from a new `runserver` command and it is still failing

Answer (score 3):

This is done using [static.serve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve)

> There may be files other than your project’s static assets that, for
>   convenience, you’d like to have Django serve for you in local
>   development. The serve() view can be used to serve any directory you
>   give it. (This view is not hardened for production use and should be
>   used only as a development aid; you should serve these files in
>   production using a real front-end web server

Change your urls.py like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just read the doc and this looks good. I am currently unable to test it. I will accept the answer later if it actually addresses my issue.

Comment: So how did it go?

Comment: I just tried and, unfortunately, it does not work :/

Comment: Quite sure that you have followed the steps religiously because this works.

Comment: This won't work, because `serve` uses STATICFILES_FINDERS, and they don't look at `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: @eugene, that's why the URL is being added there!!

Comment: @e4c5, I tried it (with 1.11 django), And it was my finding after debugging. I don't get what you mean by `URL` is added `there` .

Comment: Please look at the url patterns in my answer @eugene

Comment: @e4c5 That's exactly what I had when I tried debugging.. `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: 4 hours trying to find solution to serve my angularjs html files in django development environment

now works like a charm!.. thank you!..so much!.