# static files wont be found

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

In my base.html I am loading the static files.
In some way it will not find the path, I think.

I just want to use my static files by using:
  `{% load static %}`
  `{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}`
  `{% static 'css/style.css' %}`

This is my map structure

- ToetsOmgeving

  - _static

    - css

      - bootstrap.min.css
      - style.css
    - js
  - _templates

    - base.html
    - test

      - test_create.html
  - test
  - testenvironment

    - settings.py
  - user
  - db.sqlite3
  - manage.py

This is my settings.py:

import os

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_static')

SECRET_KEY = 'd5-f7&tlic%)*-ol)kc8$0psb+m^l_9k4!l$l(ie$#wd=#*1is'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'test',
    'user',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testenvironment.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testenvironment.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_DIR

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/_static/'),
)
```

My base.html:

```
{% load static %}
# I tried to do {% load staticfiles %} but also didn't work
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
{% block head %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %} - ToetsOmgeving!</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    {% block css %}{% endblock css %}
{% endblock head %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
{% block js %}
{% endblock js %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: STATIC_DIR says that your static files are in _static. but you have placed the css directory out of _static. If you move css directory to _static, it will work.

Comment: your static files are in _static and django will place them in static using `python manage.py collectstatic`have a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) docs

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal excuse me, I thaught I wrote it good, but it was already in the _static folder

Comment: Go to python ```manage.py shell``` and do 'from django.conf import settings'. Then print settings.BASE_DIR. See if you are giving the path correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve collected static files with Django's development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228686/how-to-serve-collected-static-files-with-djangos-development-server)

Comment: The question may look different, but the answer is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to u all guys, a stupid thing I didn't do was, adding a static folder in my `test app`

Since I added it, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your css folder under the `_static` directory as it is the STATIC_DIR

Comment: excuse me, I thaught I wrote it good, but it was already in the _static folder

Comment: and where is your `settings.py` file located

Comment: Updated it: it is in my testenvironment folder

Comment: and what error does opening `/static/css` in browser ,  return ?

Comment: 'Unresolved template reference "css/bootstrap.min.css" '

Comment: 1) I was refereing to HTTP error or success code (something like 200 , 404 , 500)

Comment: 2) Are you running from pycharm. Pycharm has a bug which does not allow to load static files.

Comment: Yes im using PyCharm, But a mate of me also use PyCharm and do not get a error.

Answer (score 0):

set `PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.path.pardir))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '_static'),`